# UPS epl label show on web page

Tags: php, ups

I am using ue UPS shipment API
...

```
<LabelSpecification>
    <LabelStockSize>
        <Height>4</Height>
        <Width>6</Width>
    </LabelStockSize>
    <LabelPrintMethod>
        <Code>EPL</Code>
        <Description>epl file</Description>
    </LabelPrintMethod>
    <HTTPUserAgent>Mozilla/4.5</HTTPUserAgent>
    <LabelImageFormat>
        <Code>GIF</Code>
        <Description>gif</Description>
    </LabelImageFormat>
    </LabelSpecification>
```

.
.
.

it's return raw format of image like 
STgsQSwwMDEKSTgsQSwwMDEKT0QKcTc5NQpRMTYwMCwyNApTMgpEMTAKSkYKTgpaVApiMTMsNDI5LE0sIjAxNSw4NDAsMTk0MDYsMDAwMCxbKT4eMDEdOTYxWjk0NjM4NzYzHVVQU04dNDRBQTE1HjA3L1RNRjItODIlKVFNKE1VQloyMDcpWEoyK0JORUlZOEorXCJcDVEgLBxZJDhEXA1cDR4EIgpBMTcsNywwLDIsMSwxLE4sIlRFU1QiCkExNywyNCwwLDIsMSwxLE4sIjExMS0xMTEtMTExMSIKQTE3LDQxLDAsMiwxLDEsTiwiMTE1MCBGSVJTVCBBVkUiCkExNyw1OCwwLDIsMSwxLE4sIktJTkcgT0YgUFJVU1NJQSAgUEEgMTk0MDYiCkE2MiwxNjQAAAAP/////....

I want to know how can I save the image to my pc and to show it on the web page.

Comment: i am try this thing but it's not show image
<embed type="application/EPL" src="aboverawformat"></embed>

Answer (score 1):

I succeed in php, using fopen and fwrite to create a gif file,such as

```
$file=fopen("temp.gif","w");
fwrite($file,base64_decode("the encoded string..."));
```

this will get a gif file,then you can put it on the web.Remenber to chown the folder where you save the gif file with apache:apache.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with UPS API but USPS returns label data base64 encoded. Maybe try and use the function base64_decode and then file_put_contents to save to disk.

Comment: i am already use this thing 
file_put_contents($time.'.gif',base64_decode($author[1][0]));
or
file_put_contents($time.'.epl',base64_decode($author[1][0]));

image size show 0 bytes.

but image not open.

Comment: You should debug and see what $author[1][0] is outputting.

Comment: output is right like STgsQSwwMDEKSTgsQSwwMDEKT0QKcTc5NQpRMTYwMCwyNApTMgpEMTAKSkYKTgpaVApiMTMsNDI5LE0sIjAxNSw4NDAsMTk0MDYsMDAwMCxbKT4eMDEdOTYxWjk0NjM4NzYzHVVQU04dNDRBQTE1HjA3L1RNRjItODIlKVFNKE1VQloyMDcpWEoyK0JORUlZOEorXCJcDVEgLBxZJDhEXA1cDR4EIgpBMTcsNywwLDIsMSwxLE4sIlRFU1QiCkExNywyNCwwLDIsMSwxLE4sIjExMS0xMTEtMTExMSIKQTE3LDQxLDAsMiwxLDEsTiwiMTE1MCBGSVJTVCBBVkUiCkExNyw1OCwwLDIsMSwxLE4sIktJTkcgT0YgUFJVU1NJQSAgUEEgMTk0MDYiCkE2MiwxNjQAAAAP/////....

but how to show in webpage ?

Comment: You should always add to your question what you did already so it is more clear what your question specifically is. This website is no wonder machine you only need to throw some broadly worded questions into to get something out.