# UPS ShipConfirm Request for label printing

Tags: xml, ups

Could anyone tell me what I need to specify in LabelSpecification section of UPS xml request document in order to print EPL shipping label? The following is what I have:

```
  <LabelSpecification>
    <LabelPrintMethod>
      <Code>EPL</Code>
    </LabelPrintMethod>
    <HTTPUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0</HTTPUserAgent>
    <LabelImageFormat>
      <Code>GIF</Code>
    </LabelImageFormat>
  </LabelSpecification>
```

But I keep getting the following error in the response:

```
Missing/Invalid Combination of LabelSpecification/LabelStockSize
```

I've tried using 'EPL2' as well with no avail. And I've no idea where to specify LabelStockSize. UPS website isn't very helpful in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yahooing](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7tlYI2FQODEAk2xXNyoA?p=UPS%20xml%20request%20document%20epl%20shipping%20label%20LabelSpecification&fr2=sb-top&fr=moz35), I found examples like [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_20950969.html):

```
<LabelSpecification>
  <LabelPrintMethod>
    <Code>EPL</Code>
  </LabelPrintMethod>
  <LabelStockSize>
    <Height>4</Height>
    <Width>6</Width>
  </LabelStockSize>
</LabelSpecification>
```

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535698/ups-epl-label-show-on-web-page):

```
<LabelSpecification>
  <LabelStockSize>
    <Height>4</Height>
    <Width>6</Width>
  </LabelStockSize>
  <LabelPrintMethod>
    <Code>EPL</Code>
    <Description>epl file</Description>
  </LabelPrintMethod>...
```

In other words, it looks like `<LabelStockSize>` needs to be a child of `<LabelSpecification>`, but can come before or after `<LabelPrintMethod>`.

Comment: Yahoo beats Google in this regard :D. Thanks for the help!